# How many displays can Intel Iris 540 support?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu

I want to get a Dell XPS 13 with i7-6560 CPU and Intel Iris 540 GPU. Question is - can the GPU support 3 displays at 1920x1080? There are enough ports to support 3 displays (a Thunderbolt 3 port can support two 4K displays and one HDMI port), but can the GPU handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intel specs are [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/91163/Intel-Core-i7-6560U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz) and it says it also depends on what Dell does with the chip.

In short:
- Doesn't say what the maximum resolutions are when used together.
- The third external connection is a wireless display.

If you want 3 external screens probably no, don't know if there even are available WiDi screens. If you want 2 plus the laptop probably yes.

Comment: Thank you for the input - even though it didn't answer the actual question I had (whether the Dell XPS 13 can support 3 monitors) - it did answer the particular question I asked - whether the GPU can support that many monitors. I should have asked the correct question. But based on my question your answer is the right one and it did lead me in the right direction to find the actual answer I was looking for, which I'll post below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Question - can Dell XPS 13 9350 (regardless of GPU - 520/540) support 3 FHD displays.

Answer - yes it can, with some extra kit.

Sources:

> Add the optional Dell Thunderbolt™ Dock for faster data transfers and
>   support for up to three Full HD displays or two 4K displays.
>   http://www.dell.com/uk/p/xps-13-9350-laptop/pd

and

> Larger, and more capable, the Dell Thunderbolt Dock comes in at 145 x
>   145 x 52 mm. It connects via Thunderbolt 3 (which uses the USB-C
>   connector type) and can drive up to three 1080p displays or two 4K
>   displays at 60 Hz. 
>   http://www.slashgear.com/dell-outs-usb-c-and-thunderbolt-3-docks-and-macs-can-play-too-06420821/